# Ordenar los objetos de un array a partir de una propiedad

Tags: javascript, array, angular, typescript, ordenamiento

Hola a todos y gracias por la ayuda de antemano, en esta ocasión necesito ordenar los objetos de un array a partir de una de sus propiedades.

**Datos importantes**

Se trata de un proyecto angular por lo cual necesito que la solución este adaptada al framework (typescript)

**Ejemplo de objeto**

```
   ordenes:
    0:
     cantidad: "1"
     estadopedido: "enviado a cocina"
     horapedido: "9:36:22 pm ,July 10th 2020"
     id: "62920c93-c2a1-44d5-a35b-87d8f2958598"
     idmesa: "2acfbd26-ddd9-4141-9aaf-85dce7082ca1"
     idproducto: "59b4f1ce-b2fc-47dd-b159-1b64e6215686"
     nombreproducto: "tocineta"
     preciototal: "3.20"
    1:
     cantidad: "1"
     estadopedido: "enviado a cocina"
     horapedido: "11:57:14 pm ,July 10th 2020"
     id: "62920c93-c2a1-44d5-a35b-87d8f2958598"
     idmesa: "2acfbd26-ddd9-4141-9aaf-85dce7082ca1"
     idproducto: "59b4f1ce-b2fc-47dd-b159-1b64e6215686"
     nombreproducto: "tocineta"
     preciototal: "3.20"
    2:
     cantidad: "1"
     estadopedido: "enviado a cocina"
     horapedido: "7:51:50 pm ,July 10th 2020"
     id: "62920c93-c2a1-44d5-a35b-87d8f2958598"
     idmesa: "2acfbd26-ddd9-4141-9aaf-85dce7082ca1"
     idproducto: "59b4f1ce-b2fc-47dd-b159-1b64e6215686"
     nombreproducto: "tocineta"
     preciototal: "3.20"
```

**Solución esperada**

La idea es ordenar los elementos en este caso 0, 1 y 2 en función de la hora en la que se realizo el pedido dando como resultado una lista ordenada de los pedidos desde el más antiguo al mas reciente (2, 0, 1).

Comment: Tu fecha es incorrecta, tiene un formato que no es traducible, debes arreglar primero tu formato de fechas porque no hay mucho que hacer con esos formatos de fecha. primero deberas arreglar tu formato de fechas.

Comment: Voy a darte un ejemplo de formato de fecha correcto que podras usar en javascript parseando la fecha, y es este: `"Fri 10 Jul 2020 07:51:50"`, tienes que corregir la forma en la que regresas los datos desde el backend o no se si lo haces desde una API, pero en este caso el formato debe ser ingles, ademas de estar en formato dia - numerodia - mes - yyyy-hh-mm-msms, ademas creo que el formato debe ser de 24h y no de 12. porfavor corrige esto, asi podre ayudarte a hacer el sort.

Comment: Vale Riven muchisimas gracias!

Comment: moment.js?, rayos, en ese caso deberas investigar por tu cuenta en la documentacion de moment.js a ver si hay alguna funcion que te formatee la fecha para que coincida con el formato que usa las fechas nativas de javascript, o aun mejor, si hay alguna que te pase ese formato a directamente numeros. porque si la fecha no esta en el formato indicado anteriormente no podras usar las fechas nativas de javascript para hacer la conversion y posteriormente hacer el ordenamiento.

Comment: No es tan difícil convertir la hora, basta con quitar las partes ordinales del día, en tu ejemplo, solo _th_: `let fecha1 = new Date('7:51:50 pm ,July 10th 2020'.replace('th', ''));` Ahora solo tienes que considerar las opciones para _1st_, _2nd_, _3rd_ y algún otro que se me escapa.

Comment: Por cierto, si realmente quieres recibir ayuda, al menos proporciona un objeto que podamos probar, seguramente te daremos enlace a una pregunta similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionaron en los comentarios, es indispensable que la fecha tenga un formato estándar. Cumpliendo este requisito, lo que yo haría es utilizar el prototype sort del objeto array (Imagino que los datos te llegan en un arreglo de objetos).
`array.prototype.sort` es un metodo nativo de un arreglo que devuelve el mismo arreglo ordenado.
Por ejemplo, utilizando el sistema unix timestamp como el formato de las fechas, pudieces realizas lo siguiente:

```
const items = [
    {
        cantidad: "1",
        estadopedido: "enviado a cocina",
        horapedido: "1595413924"
    },
    {
        cantidad: "3",
        estadopedido: "enviado a cocina",
        horapedido: "1595418504"
    },
    {
        cantidad: "2",
        estadopedido: "enviado a cocina",
        horapedido: "1595419009"
    }
]

items.sort(function (a, b) {
    // A va primero que B
    if (a.horapedido < b.horapedido)
        return -1;
    // B va primero que A
    else if (a.horapedido > b.horapedido)
        return 1;
    // A y B son iguales
    else 
        return 0;
});

console.log(items);
```

Aquí puedes encontrar mas información [sobre el metodo sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/sort)

Comment: Puedes refactorizar con `items.sort((a, b) => a.horapedido - b.horapedido)`.